# JS: RequireJS strategy: require once or each time it is necessary?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

There is something I am confused while writing modern JS (ECMA6, NodeJS, React Native)

I have a core file, which requires most of the content I need, say `app.js`:

```
var dependency1 = require('dependency1');
var dependency2 = require('dependency2');
```

And in `subfile1.js`, I'll need to access `dependency1` too. I see two ways to achieve this:

#### Solution 1: require once and forward to others

Should I write in `app.js`:

```
var subfile1 = require('./subfile1')(dependency1);
```

and in `subfile1.js`:

```
module.exports = function(dependency1) {
  var subfile1;
  // do many things;
  return subfile1;
}
```

#### Solution 2: require each time

OR in `app.js`

```
var subfile1 = require('./subfile1');
```

and in `subfile1.js`:

```
var dependency1 = require('dependency1');
module.exports = subfile1;
```

#### Comparison

My intuition is that it is cleaner to use **solution #1**, because it builds only **one** instance of each dependency.

But on the other hand, it is much more painful to write, especially when dependencies start to become numerous.

Also it fails at the *black-box* effect, which is often appreciated when writing independent modules.

My understanding is that both solutions shouldn't make a difference **iff the module is completely stateless** (ie. not calling `var dependency1 = new Dependency1()`).

Which brings me several questions:

- How can we be sure it is actually the case?
- When I am writing modules, should I keep this in mind?
- When using external modules, shouldn't the author precise whether it is stateless or not?
- Is there a best practice out-there? (writing functional code?)
- Ain't there a risk this becomes even less true with [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) available in ES6?
- Is there any impact memory-wise?
- Is what I am saying somehow wrong?

Comment: [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) keeps all loaded module instances in memory, unless you call `require.undef`, the scenario #1 is an unnecessary optimization.

Comment: CommonJS spec has the same [behavior](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching), with some nuances. Therefore CommonJS code, bundled for front-end usage by default will behave in the same way as AMD modular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js's `require` internal behavior solves your problems since modules are [cached](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching). They will be created once and you retrieve the instance after. You do not have extra problems due to statefulness with your second method but the same behavior (which is, when using stateful modules, good to know).

Furthermore, you should not have to worry about a module dependencies when you want to use it (especially, you should not have to modify your main code when a dependency is added to a submodule, especially when it is not yours).

Therefore #2 is a better approach.

In `app.js`:

```
var subfile1 = require('./subfile1');
```

In `subfile1.js`:

```
var dependency1 = require('dependency1');
var subfile1;
// many things
module.exports = subfile1;
```